# TokBox webrtc failing on iOS

Tags: ios, .net-core, webrtc, tokbox

Developed webRTC platform for 1:1, 1: many users. OK on Android, Windows (Chrome, Firefox) and MacOS (Chrome, Firefox, Safari). Fails on iOS. 1:1 ok (iOS > 11.x). More than 3 iOS users can fail. Cannot determine a pattern to find the cause. Tested on OpenTox Demo and the same issue. Using the latest SDK. TokBox support advise test has been replicated and no issues experienced. They have not suggested a starting point to determine the error. Keep referring back to SDK and their test was successful.

The primary issue being some audio streams fail. Using the latest SDK (17 at the time of writing).

As an example, we tested today (290420) and after successfully joining with 1 x Windows, 1 x macOS, I joined with iPad 11 Pro latest OS and the audio speaker failed on the iPad. I joined on iPhone 8 (iOS 13.x) and was fine.

Suggestions?

P.S. All web based using Javascript sdk

Comment: > Tested on OpenTox demo and the same issue.
It would be helpful to describe the actual issue in more detail.

Comment: @PhilippHancke thanks. I have edited to provide more info on issue.